# Auto updating an image and its thumbnail version in a document

Tags: adobe-indesign, images

I've looked around a bit and I can't seem to find what I'm looking for, hopefully you guys can help.

I'm building a calendar template for a client because he has 15-20 different calendars he needs to generate with different pictures.
He also wants the back page of the calendar to contain thumbnails of the 12 images featured in the calendar.

How can I "link" 2 image frames so that if he changes the image on page 3, it also updates the thumbnail for page 3 on the back of the calendar?

It sounds like something that could be done, but I haven't found anything because I keep finding tutorials how to span **one** image across multiple image frames, which isn't what I want to do.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: My first reaction was the "Update all occurrences" that you found. The only reason I could think that wouldn't work is if the two images ever need to differ but being a thumbnail and original that shouldn't be the case. There's no reason not to use that capability. Could you edit the "Answer" out of your question and post it as an actual Answer though so you can mark it correct for us please.

Comment: Alright, I think I just needed confirmation that there wasn't some special feature of image box linking that I was missing out on. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found that I could "modify links of all occurrences of (XYZ file)" and replace it with my new image. I tested it a bit and it seems like it respects the size and ratio of each image frame so replacing the "parent" image link sounds like it works just fine in most cases.
Here's a screenshot of my link panel (sorry it's in french)

[image]

Make sure you select the parent or else it will only replace one of the occurences.